# PHP node not passing by reference

Tags: php, dom, nodes

I have a bunch of dom manipulation functions within a class.
One of those functions assigns unique ids to specific nodes.

```
$resource_info_node->setAttribute('id', 'resource_'.$this->ids);
$details['id'] = 'resource_'.$this->ids;
$details['node'] = $resource_info_node;
$this->resource_nodes['resource_'.$this->ids] = $details;
$this->ids += 1;
```

later I want to look up and modify those nodes.
I have tried :

```
$current_node = $this->resource_nodes[$id]['node'];
```

When I print_r() I find that this node is a duplicate of the original node.
It has the original node's attributes but is not a part of the DOM tree.
I get the same results with :

```
$this->content->getElementById($id);
```

I suppose I based this whole thing on storing node references in an array. I thought that was a fine thing to do. Even if not, after that using getElementByID() should have returned the node within the dom.

I thought that, in PHP all objects were passed by reference. Including DOM nodes.
Any ideas on how I can test what is actually going on.

**EDIT :**

Well I used :

```
$this->xpath->query('//*[@id]');
```

That returned the right number of items with ids. The node is just not in the DOM tree when I edit it.

and

```
$current_node = &$this->resource_nodes[$id]['node'];
```

Using the reference syntax had no affect.

The strangest part is that get elementById() is not returning a node in the dom. It has all the right attributes except no parentNode.

**FIX - not answer :**

I just used xpath instead of my reference or getElementById().

Answer (score 3):

Use reference explicity:

```
$current_node = &$this->resource_nodes[$id]['node'];
```

And modify `$current_node`